# Finding multiple JSON elements in a string for replacement and pretty-printing

Tags: python, json, regex

Although I found quite a few topics regarding regex and JSON, I don't see the end of the tunnel. This is about finding JSON-elements in log files using python (it is in Splunk).

Someone found it a good idea to log objects in JSON notation like so:

- There are always 10 [.*]-pairs at the beginning of a line.
- one of them can contain pseudo-JSON, having curly brackets, but not properly formatted. I am not interested in those
- There can be none, one or two JSON-objects in a line
- They can be single objects {} or arrays [], containing nested JSON

These are the examples.

```
m1='''[][{st=82, fl=FX}][][][][][][][][] nnn {"1":"A"} mmm'''
m2='''[][][{st=82, fl=FX}][][][][][][][] nnn {"1":"A"} xxx {"2":"B"} mmm'''
m3='''[][][][{st=82, fl=FX}][][][][][][] nnn [{"1":"A"},{"2":"B"}] mmm'''
m4='''[][][][][{st=82, fl=FX}][][][][][] nnn {"1":"A"} aaa [{"2":"B"},{"3":"C"}] mmm'''
m5='''[][][][][][{st=82, fl=FX}][][][][] nnn [{"1":"A"},{"2":"B"}] bbb {"3":"C"} mmm'''
m6='''[][][][][][][{st=82, fl=FX}][][][] nnn [{"1":"A"},{"2":"B"}] ccc [{"3":"C"},{"4":"D","5":"E"}] mmm'''
```

I was going to remove each JSON-object and replace it by its pretty-print using `json.dumps()` in Python.

The remainder of the line needs to stay as it was, i.e. the header and any extra text.

Doing it in one go seems to be impossible. So I try to make two iterations, the first of which to replace the JSON-arrays, and the second one to do the rest. Like so:

```
m=m6
for match in re.finditer('(\[{.*?}\])',m):
   print json.dumps(match.group(1) , sort_keys=False,
                    indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

for match in re.finditer('({.*?})',m):
   print json.dumps(match.group(1), sort_keys=False,
                    indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

I'm having these issues:

- match.group() seems to be returning a string, which json.dumps() does not parse.
- for the replace-part I have no idea, yet.
- Is this going to be fast enough? or is it the wrong approach?

Getting:

```
"[{\"3\":\"C\"},{\"4\":\"D\",\"5\":\"E\"}]"
```

Expected:

```
[
    {
        "3": "C"
    },
    {
        "4": "D",
        "5": "E"
    }
]
```

This would do it:

```
print json.dumps([{"3":"C"},{"4":"D","5":"E"}], sort_keys=False,
                     indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: Yeah, you are going to have to deal with `{st=82, fl=FX}` which is not valid JSON.  Your first iteration doesn't do any replacing as far as I can tell, and will fall when it matches the above and the string gets passed to `json.dumps`

Comment: Correct. As I said, no idea yet about the replacing part. Failing with the invalid json-element would be a minor issue - it could be caught and disregarded? What worries me is the return-string by match(), which is not a json-element at all with these escaped quotas.